# How to send a ping request over a tls connection?

Tags: node.js, tls1.2

I am using below code from client to connect a tls server,

I need to send a ping request from client to server,
Image below has the documentation.
[image]

```
// Assumes an echo server that is listening on port 8000.
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  // Necessary only if the server requires client certificate authentication.
  key: fs.readFileSync('client-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem'),

  // Necessary only if the server uses a self-signed certificate.
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem') ],

  // Necessary only if the server's cert isn't for "localhost".
  checkServerIdentity: () => { return null; },
};

const socket = tls.connect(8000, options, () => {
  console.log('client connected',
              socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
  process.stdin.pipe(socket);
  process.stdin.resume();
});
socket.setEncoding('utf8');
socket.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
socket.on('end', () => {
  console.log('server ends connection');
});
```

Can someone please help me figure out how to send data over tls connection from client to server side.

Comment: did you find a way to do this? I'm trying to ping a server at port 587 with no success :(

Comment: what is the error you are receiving? @Lo